# Utf-8 issues with python and nltk

Tags: python, string, utf-8, nlp, nltk

I have this little script, which is basically just a test I'm doing for a larger program. I have a problem with the encoding. When I try to write to file the utf-8 characters, such as øæå, are not encoded properly. Why is that, and how can I solve this issue?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *

collocations = open('bam.txt', 'w')
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize("Hei på deg øyerusk, du er meg en gammel dust, neida neida, det er ikke helt sant da."
                                 "Men du, hvorfor så brusk, ikke klut i din susk på en runkete lust")
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
# finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
scored = finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.raw_freq)
for i in scored:
    print i[0][0] + ' ' + i[0][1] + ': ' + str(i[1]) + '\n'
    collocations.write(i[0][0] + ' ' + i[0][1] + ': ' + str(i[1]) + '\n')

collocations.close()
```

Comment: if you downvote, provide a reason.

Comment: Should this work on non-english? (I didn't downvote), seems all results (in `print ..`) are the same.

Comment: I assume it works with non-english. The results are the same because there are no collocations, but a different string would give different result in the frequencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is `nltk.wordpunct_tokenize` doesn't work with non-ascii data. It is better to use `PunktWordTokenizer` from `nltk.tokenize.punkt`. So import is as:

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktWordTokenizer as PT
```

and replace:

```
tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize("Hei på deg øyerusk, du er meg en gammel dust, neida neida, det er ikke helt sant da."
                             "Men du, hvorfor så brusk, ikke klut i din susk på en runkete lust")
```

with:

```
tokens = PT().tokenize("Hei på deg øyerusk, du er meg en gammel dust, neida neida, det er ikke helt sant da." 
                             "Men du, hvorfor så brusk, ikke klut i din susk på en runkete lust")
```

Comment: cant import punkt anymore any help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questins/36836481/nltk-remove-tags-from-parsed-chunks  there is no error traceback but you can help maybe thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of reasons why the encoding isn't working properly. Unicode is a vast and varied mess. The Python HOWTO on Unicode is somewhat helpful for background info: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

When I just need stuffy to work, I've had success forcing encodings into unicode by using `ftfy`,  available on PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftfy/3.3.0

Example usage:

```
>>>import ftfy
>>> print(ftfy.fix_text('uÌˆnicode'))
ünicode

>>>print(ftfy.fix_text_encoding('AHÅ™, the new sofa from IKEA®'))
AHÅ™, the new sofa from IKEA®
```